# Turning a string into html using MarkupString

Tags: c#, html, razor, github-api, rest

I'm trying to get the content of a `README.md` file from a github repo and display it's outtput on a webpage (using razor), here is my code:

```
@using System.Net.Http.Headers;
@using Newtonsoft.Json;

@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<span>
    @((MarkupString)content)
</span>


@code{

    public string content { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
        const string url = "https://api.github.com/repos/angrymonkeydocs/amd-css/contents/README.md";
        HttpClient client = new();

        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "AngryMonkeyDocs");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("AngryMonkeyDocs", "1"));
        string responseString = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
        string jsonContent = json["content"];

        content = Base64Decode(jsonContent);
        
    }


    private static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
    {
        var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
    }
}
```

And here is the result:
[image]

however here is the webpage url: https://github.com/angrymonkeydocs/amd-css#readme

I don't understand why am I getting the following results instead of it being like the webpage

Comment: The API return the [raw content](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angrymonkeydocs/amd-css/main/README.md) in markdown language. But the markdown need be converted to HTML to be displayed in a browser.

Comment: The GitHub API seems to have a [endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/markdown) to convert markdown to HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .md file is a markdown file. It's not HTML. Github takes the markdown and formats it into HTML when it shows it. You can convert it to HTML yourself using something like [markdig](https://github.com/xoofx/markdig).